# Data chegando incorreta

Tags: java, ajax, spring, data

Estou com o seguinte problema aqui: Eu tenho uma requisição que eu faço pelo ajax, e envio uma data por ela, o java recebe e salva no banco, porem a data que chega no java é diferente da que eu enviei. Segue os codigos:

Requisição ajax:

```
var episodio = {
    titulo  : $('#inputTitulo').val(),
    descricao : $('#textSinopse').val(),
    sneakPeak : $('#inputTrailer').val(),
    dataEstreia : $('#inputDataEstreia').val(),
    numero  : $('#inputNumero').val(),
    duracao : $('#inputDuracao').val()
};  

$.ajax({
    url: '/seriesmais/ajax/episodio/',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: episodio,
    success: function(episodioRecebida) {
        alert('inseriu');
    }
});
```

Método no controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> salvar(Episodio episodio) {
    System.out.println(episodio);

    try {

        if (episodio.getId() == null){
            System.out.println("DATA: " + episodio.getDataEstreia());
            daoEpisodio.inserir(episodio);
        } else {
            daoEpisodio.alterar(episodio);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(episodio);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
    }

}
```

Data no model(estava usando sem a anotação DateTimeFormat, e não funcionava também, coloquei para ver se funcionava, não funcionou):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date dataEstreia;
```

Eu estou pegando a data do bootstrap datepicker, porem a data que sai dele é correta:

[image]

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
weekStart:1,
format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Mas a data que chega no java é outra: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu geralmente evito enviar datas formatadas como parâmetros ou respostas de requsições. Sempre utilizo o formato UTC Timestamp e faço a conversão/formatação em client side. Isso evita uma série de problemas.

Por exemplo, se quero enviar a data 22/12/2016 11:54:59 como resposta, envio essa data no formato UTC (1482407699000).

No lado do cliente faço a conversão e a posterior formatação:

```
getDate: function(timestamp)
{
// Multiply by 1000 because JS works in milliseconds instead of the UNIX seconds
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-indexed, so we'll increment to get the correct month number
var day = date.getUTCDate();
var hours = date.getUTCHours();
var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();

month = (month < 10) ? '0' + month : month;
day = (day < 10) ? '0' + day : day;
hours = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;
minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds: seconds;

return year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes;
}
```

Referências:
https://blog.serverdensity.com/automatic-timezone-conversion-in-javascript/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc
http://www.epochconverter.com